# Include external files from conf files

Tags: centos

I have large and messy conf files for postfix, dovecot and opendkim. I want to tidy these up by creating a sub folder called domains and creating a conf file for each domain. Then from the root file i can include each of these files in order to keep things tidy.

I have tried doing this the same way it is done in the apache conf files and it isnt working. I have also tried.

> !include /etc/dovecot/domains/website.com

Is there a standard way that i can reference another conf file  from within another conf file in linux ?

Im using centos 7

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard; each application will have its own configuration file parsing that may or may not support includes. For applications that do not support includes, one might `(cat headerstuff; cat somedir/foo*; cat footerstuff) > mainconfig` to build the configuration file from a suite of files, or use equivalent support in configuration management software to assemble the config file.